# How to change AMI image in the existing Spotinst Elasticgroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to change AMI image in Spotinst Elasticgroup and to respinup active instances. How to implement it with the `spotinst-sdk-python` having `SPOTINST_TOKEN` and `SPOTINST_ACCOUNT` env variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example CLI tool leveraging the spotinst_sdk2 for python. This tool can do the following:

- get/list all EG IDs
- update an AMI for an EG
- roll an EG.

#### get details via help

`python3 roll_eg.py --help`

#### list all EG and their ID

`python3 roll_eg.py get`

#### Update AMI and roll EG

`python3 roll_eg.py roll -a ami-e3fdd999 sig-1234567`

Script Location:
https://github.com/spotinst/spotinst-examples/tree/master/Utilities/AWS/Update%20AMI%20and%20roll%20Elastigroup